# How to import specific text/line under headings in Google doc to Google sheet using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am trying to get specific text/line that is under the heading or subheading using the google apps script. Here is the screenshot of the Google doc:

> [image: Google sheets]

I am looking to export the Question text/line from every heading to google sheets like this:

> [image: Google sheet]

So far I have been able to get all the headings from the google doc by this code snippet:

```
function getHeadings() {
  var pars = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs();
  var hdg = [];
  for(var i=0; i<pars.length; i++) {
    var par = pars[i];
    hdg.push(par.getHeading());

  }
     Logger.log(hdg)
}
```

But I am unable to get the Question text under all these headings, kindly can you guide me in the right direction? (I apologize for my question formatting, I am a newbie on this website). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of assumptions for this script:

- There is a finite number of header styles you're using (e.g. 'Header 1' and 'Header 2' in my example below)
- Your questions always contain 'QUESTION'
- There is no other text apart from the headers and the question lines (but if there is, in principle it will be skipped)

In that case, the below code will work:

```
function getHeadings() {
  var pars = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs();
  var currentHdg = "";
  var questions = [];
  for(var i=0; i<pars.length; i++) {
    var par = pars[i];
    var text = par.getText();
    var hdg = par.getHeading();
    if (hdg.toString().indexOf("HEADING") > -1){
      currentHdg = text;
    }
    else if(text.indexOf("QUESTION") > -1){
      questions.push([currentHdg,text.replace("QUESTION","").trim()]);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(questions);
}
```

You can then format `questions` into the table output format you need.

**Edit:** I have updated my answer to cover all heading types.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, the solution looks for h1 and h2, however, there can be other headings and subheadings in the google doc, how can we cover all other headings

Comment: Thanks @Sohaib435, I have edited my original answer to cover all headings

Comment: Thank you but it only gives output for heading 2, like this: `[[Heading 2, This is the first question in Heading 2.]]`

Comment: I think I found the issue, instead of `text.indexOf("QUESTION:")` we need to use `text.indexOf("QUESTION")`

Comment: Ah yes, it looks like you also have question numbers so matching for ```QUESTION``` only is more appropriate. Note that you will also have to get rid of the colons. I will edit my answer again for completeness. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Use getChild() and and push() functions

### Setup

I used the following as setup:

[image: test]

### Script

```
function getHeadings() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var childNum = doc.getBody().getNumChildren();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<spreadsheetID>").getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //Change ID of Spreadsheet and Sheet name
  var out = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < childNum; i += 2) {
    out.push([doc.getBody().getChild(i).asText().getText()]);
  }
  for (var i = 1, j = 0; i < childNum; i += 2, j++) {
    out[j].push(doc.getBody().getChild(i).asText().getText().replace(/Question(.*)- /gm, ""));
  }
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1, 1, childNum / 2, 2).setValues(out); //edit range to proper coordinates
}
```

The script uses the `getChild()` function to get the texts in the document. Afterwards, the `getNumChildren()` will get the number of children to be used in the two separate for loops which will segregate the heading and the question texts. After the texts are identified, they are separated, paired, and then pushed (using the `push()` function) into arrays. Once the arrays are formed, the data will be appended to the spreadsheet using the `setValues()` function.

### Output

[image: output]

### Update

Strictly for this format:
[image: setup 2]

You may use the following script as basis for your code:

```
function getHeadings() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var childNum = doc.getBody().getNumChildren();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<SpreadsheetID>").getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //Change ID of Spreadsheet and Sheet name
  var header = [];
  var question = [];
  var out = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < childNum; i++) {
    if (doc.getBody().getChild(i).asText().getText().match(/Header(.*)/gm)){
      header.push(doc.getBody().getChild(i).asText().getText());
    }
    else if (doc.getBody().getChild(i).asText().getText().match(/Question(.*)/gm)){
      question.push(doc.getBody().getChild(i).asText().getText());
    }
  }
  for (j=0; j<header.length; j++) {
    out.push([header[j]]);
    out[j].push(question[j].replace(/Question(.*)- /gm, ""));
  }
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1, 1, header.length, 2).setValues(out); //edit range to proper coordinates
}
```

### References:

- [getChild()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getchildname)
- [getNumChildren()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/container-element#getnumchildren)
- [push()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)
- [replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: I ran your answer code, due to the difference in your input text and mine, there is a difference in the output. It is taking text other than Question text also i.e (some other text)

Comment: As of now  the script only works if the document format in my sample data is followed. I am still trying to figure out how to ignore the unnecessary data.

Comment: I have added an update wherein you may use as basis for your script.